# What is the affection of stress tensor of spacetime by the energy/mass density moment of a photon?

Tags: general-relativity, photons, mass-energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, multipole-expansion

First of all what kind of moment exhibits the photon under its propagation to spacetime continium -quadrupole,dipole or monopole! Please, explain me- why. Do Give some arguements! When it propagetes does it exegerate gravitatinal waves? Why only quadrupoles do that ?

Comment: Is this a follow-up from your previous question about [photons and gravitational waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/do-photons-generate-gravitational-waves-since-they-affect-with-their-energy-the)? Perhaps you should expand that question there to attract more people willing to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Because gravity is a tensor field, and the lowest excitation is quadrupole.  For a vector field it would be a dipole; and for a scalar field it is what you have termed a monopole: like a frog croaking, or the fundamental mode of a drum, it just goes all in, and all out.

The terminology derives from the terms of a multipole series expansion, ususally first studied in electromagnetic field theory, or a course in mathematical physics.

Comment: Yes ,it merges from my previous question? And as in my previous ,in this one I still litteraly don't have any exact answer. Does photon creates create GW in its propagation. Can it have quadrupole moment? Why, so ?

Comment: The photon is a vector particle, as it originates in the vector electromagnetic field.  So no, a photon could not create a gravitational wave.  Of course, you can make a quadrupole field from two dipoles: you can do this with two magnets.  So under the proper conditions you could generate a gravitational wave with two photons, in the proper configuration - they would have to exist in the region to be disturbed simultaneously, and would have to cross at an angle.  Consider how LIGO works: if it can detect, it may also be able to generate - but at an impossibly low level, impossible to detec.

Comment: Would you please explain why the way is impossible for detection? But please no answers like the field is negligible or the filed is mega turbo giga small . Negligible or very very very small does not make any sense for me .
Only values make it !