# Gravitational wave due to photon?

Tags: general-relativity, photons, gravitational-waves

Does photons create gravitational waves as they travel through space?

I know that when matter particle moves, they create gravitational waves but does that same thing applies to photons as well and if so then how does it work?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/do-photons-generate-gravitational-waves-since-they-affect-with-their-energy-the

Comment: You might be interested in the **Aichelburg-Sexl metric**. The original reference is [On the gravitational field of a massless particle](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00758149).

Comment: When matter particles move, photons are radiated. Maybe gravitational waves are made up of photons.

Comment: @BillAlsept In mainstream physics, gravitational waves are not made up of photons.

Comment: *I know that when matter particle moves, they create gravitational waves* A matter particle moving uniformly does not radiate gravitational waves. Nor does a rotating sphere. Some kinds of motion cause gravitational waves and others don’t.

Comment: @G.Smith A lot of people also believe that electromagnetic waves are not made a photons.